# Check the availability of an generic interface in a collection

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I have the following classes and the name of the entity as **strings**. They can be 'Customer' or 'Order'.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
}

public class Customer
{
}

public class Product
{
}

public class CustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>
{
}

public class ProductRepository : IRepository<Product>
{
}

var repositoryTypes = new List<????>()
{
     ????
}
```

1. How can I create a list of the interfaces as `repositoryTypes`?
2. How can I search the collection for the entity name like 'Customer' or 'Product' to find the repository interface? Note that `Customer` is a string type.
3. Is there a C# 6 or 7 language feature make the solution easy?

Comment: I don't necessarily understand the need for the list of repository types, if they are all going to be same type having a different generic argument.

Comment: I have to get the type and then resolve it from a ```IoC``` container.